# Как получить PID запущенного процесса без ожидания его завершения?

Tags: python, linux, консоль, процесс

Моя задача - запустить процесс, и сохранить его PID у себя в программе, то есть в моем скрипте выполняется:

```py
pid = os.popen(f'python3 {path} & echo $!')
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после выполнения этой команды моя программа повисает, потому что ждет завершения скрипта, который запущен через `popen`. А мне нужно продолжать ее работу. Можно было бы выполнять `popen` в отдельном потоке, но я думал, что есть другие пути решения этой проблемы. Тем более таких программ может быть много.

Comment: Асинхронно запустить процесс: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor Получить его PID: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid